# PCI Express x16 what does this mean?

Tags: graphics-card

What does PCI Express x16 mean?  To replace a video card what information would I need to know about specs I need to look at on PC and replacement graphic card to be sure if fits?

Answer (score 1):

PCI Express x16 means that there are 16 communication channels in the interface between the motherboard and video card. If your motherboard has a PCIx x16 slot, then you can get a PCIx x16 card (best) or any number of channels down to PCIx x1. If your motherboard only has a PCIX x8 slot, a PCIx x16 card will not fit in it.